# How to make ImageButton repeat a sound each time it's clicked

Tags: android, audio, imagebutton, playback

I am trying to get the Image Button to play a sound each time it's clicked. For example, if the sound is playing for few seconds and I press the button again it should start from the beginning. I managed to get the sound working but it's not repeating it. How can I get it to start over?

```
ImageButton bt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bt = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.clickme);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bird);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.bird);
        }
        mp.start();
    } catch(Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for reply but am getting error . cannot resolve symbol context.

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Error:(28, 25) error: cannot assign a value to final variable mp
Error:(28, 49) error: cannot find symbol variable context

Comment: Try `getApplicationContext()`, `getActivity()`, `getBaseContext()` or `this`. One of these will work, depending on where your code currently is running from. `context` means to use your context https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Comment: hi it worked using getBaseContext(). i have spend two days trying to figure out this, i wanted to try my best to resolve on my own, but sometimes its best to ask pros, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use MediaPlayer.seekto() to seek to the start of the audio file.

```
ImageButton bt;
private MediaPlayer mp = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bt = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.clickme);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bird);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(mp.isPlaying()) {
                 mp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                 mp.start();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: hi, thank you for reply but this code did not work, the sound does not play at all.